# QuickSort Algorithm what is next step once first pivot is located its final position in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, quicksort

Currently trying to understand how the QuickSort Algorithm operates before I implement it into code, I have the unsorted array:

```
{7,8,2,5,1,9,3,6}
```

In the case of this question, the right most element in the array has been picked as the pivot, 6.
I have gone through the array comparing each element with 6(pivot) and depending if the array element is less than or bigger than six, done the appropriate action. As a result, now all values less than 6 are on the left and all values greater than 6 are on the right
The array now looks like this

```
{2,5,1,3,6,7,9,8}.
```

As many tutorials have stated we now essentially have two smaller arrays

```
{2,5,1,3} and {7,9,8}
```

I am stuck here on what to do next, as every different tutorial picks a different pivot point making it hard to follow.
Do i do the same thing again in my two smaller arrays?

If someone could show me how to sort the `{2,5,3,1}` array and explain how you did it that would be great I will then do `{7,9,8}` myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the same thing on two segments once you got the position of your first pivot. Call method on left and right segments recursively.

Now partition on your two subsets `{2,5,1,3}` and `{7,9,8}`.
You will pick 3 as pivot on `{2,5,1,3}` and get `{2,1}` and `{5}` for first segment and do similar for the other segment.

```
{2,5,1,3} 
       ^
{2,1,3,5}
     ^
pivot (3) at proper position. do the same on left and right segments.

{2,1} and {5}
   ^

{1,2,3,5}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following animated representation explains how to find the pivot value in an array.

[image]

The pivot value divides the list into two parts. And recursively, we find the pivot for each sub-lists until all lists contains only one element.

**Steps to achieve QuickSort algorithm:**

Step 1 − Choose the highest index value as pivot (can be any index)

Step 2 − Take two variables to point left and right of the list excluding pivot

Step 3 − left points to the low index

Step 4 − right points to the high

Step 5 − while value at left is less than pivot move right

Step 6 − while value at right is greater than pivot move left

Step 7 − if both step 5 and step 6 does not match swap left and right

Step 8 − if left ≥ right, the point where they met is new pivot

The pseudocode for the above algorithm can be derived as −

```
function partitionFunc(left, right, pivot)
   leftPointer = left -1
   rightPointer = right

   while True do
      while A[++leftPointer] < pivot do
         //do-nothing            
      end while

      while rightPointer > 0 && A[--rightPointer] > pivot do
         //do-nothing         
      end while

      if leftPointer >= rightPointer
         break
      else                
         swap leftPointer,rightPointer
      end if

   end while 

   swap leftPointer,right
   return leftPointer

end function
```

**Quick Sort Algorithm**

Using pivot algorithm recursively, we end up with smaller possible partitions. Each partition is then processed for quick sort. We define recursive algorithm for quicksort as follows −

Step 1 − Make the right-most index value pivot

Step 2 − partition the array using pivot value

Step 3 − quicksort left partition recursively

Step 4 − quicksort right partition recursively

**Quick Sort Pseudocode**

To get more into it, let's see the pseudocode for quick sort algorithm −

```
procedure quickSort(left, right)

   if right-left <= 0
      return
   else     
      pivot = A[right]
      partition = partitionFunc(left, right, pivot)
      quickSort(left,partition-1)
      quickSort(partition+1,right)    
   end if       

end procedure
```

Answer (score 1):

The way QuickSort works is through a recursive procedure, which is the procedure you have described. Applying the same procedure on both resulting arrays and you will be fine.

Just to clarify, the base case of this algorithm is when the size of the input array is one, resulting in a sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to:

> I am stuck here on what to do next, as every different tutorial picks
>   a different pivot point making it hard to follow.

The pivot can be chosen on many different ways, even randomly. Average performance of quick sort is O(n*log n), but worst-case is O(n^2). Depending on which way the pivot is being chosen, the algorithm is more reliable when sorting some "end-case" arrays and thus, the number of cases where its performance is O(n^2) is smaller.